# Переменные в shell

Tags: shell

Добрый день! Вопрос: имеется несколько переменных допустим var_1024="1",var_2048="2" etc... за ранее количество переменных не известно.Каким образом можно ссылаться в скрипте на каждую переменную не зная их имена?

Comment: Эээ... А что же все-таки известно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я так понял, нужно конструировать имена переменных и потом с ними работать.

Можно с помощью eval

```
i=33
eval var_$i="AAAA"
eval echo \$var_$i
```

Создается переменная `var_33`, ей присваивается значение и потом оно печатается в `echo`.

Если имя одной переменной присвоить другой переменной, то есть еще один способ обращаться к ее значению

```
var_1="AAA"
n=1
nam="var_$n"
echo ${!nam}
eval "echo \$$nam" #то же самое
```

Comment: второй вариант спс.

Answer (score 1):

Может как нибудь так:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A `set | grep ^VAR | sed -e 's/^VAR_[0-9]\+/a[\0]/'`
for i in ${!a[@]}
do
    echo $i ${a[$i]}
done
```

Переменные VAR_xxxx должны при этом экспортироваться в скрипт. Ну если порядок нет тот -- сортировать. Если ассоциативный массив не нужен, то

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `set | grep ^VAR`
do
    echo $i
done
```

или ещё как-нибудь

Comment: не совсем то

Comment: но все равно круто